# How do I print a list from views.py to the console?

Tags: python, django

I'm a near-total newbie to Django, and am trying to debug a piece of code which is returning a null list to a template even though it should be returning a list with items in it. Is there any way to print the list to the console from within views.py for debugging purposes? I obviously can't run `python views.py` as the info I want is stored in a SQLite database, but if I try to include a `print` statement within the view I'm using, nothing prints when I refresh the page (and the server contacts my code). Is there a solution? I've looked around for a long time and can't find anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, you never run Django code with `python views.py`

However, you can see each HTTP request in your console that you open to start your local Django webserver.

If you do e.g. in your `index()` view function `print`, you should be able to see the output directly in your console:

```
def index(request):
   a_list = [1,2,3,4]
   print a_list
   return render(request, 'index.html', {'list':a_list})
```

ask if something is unclear to you ;)

Comment: While I still consider my answer correct, yours is more complete, so +1

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the **runserver** command, you will see the output of print-statements in that command prompt, like a live logging.

Comment: Only if the statements are contained within a view function.

Comment: See question... He wants to debug bis view.

Answer (score 5):

You could just include a debug line in your view function. Your views.py would look like :

```
import pdb

def myview(request):
    ...
    pdb.set_trace()
    ...
```

When running `python manage.py runserver`and querying the corresponding url in your browser, your command line will stop on the `pdb.set_trace()`. You can then explore and test everything you want.